# Changing Windows Domain from subdomain.example.com to just example.com

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2019

Hello and thanks for taking the time to read and respond to this.

We have a Server 2012 R2 domain, that is setup with domain/forest like subdomain.example.com. We would like to smoothly move, if possible, to just example.com, while upgrading to 2019.

What would be the smoothest way to accomplish this domain name move, while maintaining our AD users/groups/structure?

Comment: What you're proposing is counter to current best practice. Might I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Using a domain is counter to current best practices (vs a subdomain), or moving? The reason is that years ago, we read that subdomain was the best practice. The subdomain was a certain city name, and now that netbios name is everywhere and doesn't make sense. We'd like to eliminate it, so while also effectively shortening the length of our FQDNs.